# grantOfflineAccess is not working with scope

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-api-js-client, google-api-javascript-client

I am using google API's in my angular 8 website. I have to integrate Google Drive and YouTube account on different buttons.

1. YouTube Connect button
2. Google Drive Connect button

I init gapi as

```
  initGoogleAccounts() {
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
  this.googleUser = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: this.env.google_client_id,
    fetch_basic_profile: false,
    scope: 'profile'
  });
});
```

}

On Youtube button click

```
    this.googleUser.grantOfflineAccess('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl').then(({code}) => {
  this.youtubeCodeConnect(code);
});
```

But this is not asking for Youtube permissions.
Is there anything which i am doing wrong?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergrantofflineaccessoptions  your not asking for the offline scopes